# How to Change Date from new to old date when creating new record in ASP.NET CORE MVC

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

For example I created a record in assigned asset with asset code (lap001), employee name (hana) and date (08/10/21).

Then I created another record with the same asset code (lap001) different employee name (lana) and date(09/10/21). in other words I have assigned this asset to diffrent employee.

In asset master details of that specific asset code (lap001) screen how to show that this specific asset was assigned to this employee from previous date (08/10/21) to new date (09/10/21).

Now currently Date in AssigningAssetModel is assigned to AssignedToDateNew now how to move the new date to old date when I create a new record and also how to prevent user to put date between previous date (08/10/21) to new date (09/10/21)

**AssigningAssetModel** class:

```
public class AssigningAssetModel
{
    [key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Employee Name")]
    public string EmployeeName {get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter AssetCode")]
    public string AssetCode { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Date")]
    public string Date{ get; set; }
}
```

**AssetMasterModel** class:

```
public class AssetMasterModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get ;set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter AssetCode")] 
    public string AssetCode { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Employee Name")]
    public string EmployeeName{ get; set; }

    public string AssignedToDateOld { get; set; }

    public string AssignedToDateNew { get; set; }
}
```

**AssigningAsset** controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(int id, [Bind("ID,EmployeeName,AssetCode,Date,")] AssigningAssetModel assigningAssetModel)
{            
    if (id != assigningAssetModel.ID) 
        return NotFound();

    if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
        return View(assigningAssetModel);

    try
    {
        var masterExist = await _context.Set<AssetMasterModel>()
                                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync( i => i.AssetCode == assigningAssetModel.AssetCode);

        if (masterExist == null) 
            return NotFound();

        if (masterExist.EmployeeName != assigningAssetModel.EmployeeName)
        {
            masterExist.EmployeeName = assigningAssetModel.EmployeeName;
            masterExist.AssignedToDateNew = assigningAssetModel.Date;
                                
            _context.Entry(masterExist).State=EntityState.Modified;
        }

        _context.Add(assigningAssetModel);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        _context.Update(assigningAssetModel);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

**AssetMaster** controller:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var assetMasterModel = await _context.AssetMaster
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
        if (assetMasterModel == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(assetMasterModel);
    }
```

So basically in [Assigning Asset Index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBDEi.png) this asset code (laptop0001015) is first assigned to Tom at 22/05/2021 then it has been assigned to Mouffaq at 24/05/2021 now in assetmaster how to show that this asset code in this case (Laptop0001015) was assigned to Tom From 22/05/2021 to 24/05/2021

Comment: I am sorry but it is hard to understand what do you need. Can you post a detail example what values were before you added a new record, and what values do you want to see after?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking but there are several serious problems. For starters, `DateTime` is a binary type, it has no format. There's no good reason to use `string` to store dates. Second, two-digit years reintroduce the Year-2000, only one year after major banks like Lloyd's and RBS went offline when `20` was treated as `1920`. There's absolutely no excuse for using two-digit years in 2021.

Comment: Using strings instead of DateTime makes querying extremely hard if not impossible. For starters, there's no way to even guess what the string format is. Unless the string is in `YY/MM/DD` format, you can only search for exact matches, because the database will use alphabetic (lexicographical) ordering. You won't be able to search for every date in 2021 for example, or for dates in a certain period

Comment: Another equally serious bug is using `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` multiple times. Don't do that. A DbContext caches all changes and persists them in a single transaction when you call `SaveChanges`. If something goes wrong, all changes are rolled back automatically. No other connections will see the changes until the transaction completes. Your code on the other hand stores changes object by object, which means partial changes are visible to others. If something goes wrong, only half of the changes will be rolled back, resulting in inconsistent data

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the only reason I don't put DateTime is because date is autogenerated when record is created so it is not manually entered by the user

Comment: @sergey it is simple but it is hard to explain the logic the concept is to show that this asset code has been assigned to this employee from this date to this date

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, what you need to do is keep the existing asset date before creating the new record and then assign it to the new record.

```cs
prevDate = employee.getCurrentAsset().date
newAsset = new Asset()
newAsset.date = prevDate ;
employee.setCurrentAsset(newAsset) ;
```